# Binary tree creation from Array objects in Angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an array object that displays as rows with the input control and values. This values displays based on object value status true or false as my sample link below . Once table generated based on array values while select/deselect the checkbox the binary selection should happen and that needs to be updated into new array as mentioned the post "output should be. [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5fomh9b3/) the sample of work. Is this achievable smart way?

```
 Actual scenario is the following, needs to convert binary tree based on "show"  true value.

{ Row: "1",
      RowValues: [ 
       {td:"1", show: true},
       {td:"2", show: true},
       {td:"3", show: true},
       {td:"4", show: true},
       {td:"5", show: true}
       ]
     },


    { Row: "2",
      RowValues: [ 
       {td:"6", show: false},
       {td:"7", show: false},
       {td:"8", show: false},
       {td:"9", show: true},
       {td:"10", show: false}
       ]
     },

     { Row: "3",
      RowValues: [ 
       {td:"11", show: false},
       {td:"12", show: false},
       {td:"13", show: true},
       {td:"14", show: true}
       ]
     },

      { Row: "4",
      RowValues: [ 
       {td:"15", show: false},
       {td:"16", show: false},
       {td:"17", show: false},
       {td:"18", show: true}
       ]
     }

    ]


Scenario is 
    1   2   3   4   5
                9   
            13  14
                18

while selecting the node 18
**output should be** [1,2,13,18]

Scenario is 
    1   2   3   4   5
                9   
            13  14
                18

 while selecting the node 3
  **output should be** [1,2,3,4, 5,9]
```

Comment: your behavior are very unclear, could you explain step by step how you manipulate the input to have the output ?

Comment: The Framework is not clear. Do you mean [angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) or [Angular](https://angular.io/)? Because the headline differs from tagging

Comment: @Bernhard: It is angular js please check the link "here" in post.

Comment: @Yanis-git : Updated the post

Comment: sorry but i still not understand how you can `[1,2,3,4,5,9]` when you select node 3

Comment: @ Yanis-git : I was asking can we achievable that scenario